# Applying sound effects based on pitch, speed and rate

Tags: java, android, audio, voice, soundeffect

I would like to apply some voice change filter based on those standard variables. Does anybody tried it before and knows how to adjust them to get the standard voices like helium, robotic or zombie? Maybe some tool or any advice how to test it, or other resources ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop your own methods to do it, it is not an easy thing to do. You should get some experience on signal processing to make all of the things you mentioned. Detecting the pitch (frequency) of a sound is a good start, and then it comes to pitch shifting and modifying the waveform to generate robotic voice (distortion) etc. It will take some time.

If you want to produce things quickly, I would suggest you to use a library to make almost all of the work, such as [Aubio](http://aubio.org/).

Comment: Yes. I just want to apply sound effects like baloon/monster/etc I know it is subjective. But this library does not seem to be supported with android. Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried it but not for Android. What I was doing was to detect notes by an instrument and create a midi version of what I play with guitar.  Written in C++ so I think you can find a way to port it.